# Probability of 2 independent events and 1 mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space for an experiment $E$ and let $A,B,C\subset \Omega$. If events $A,B$ are independent, events $A,C$ are disjoint, and events $B,C$ are independent, find $\Pr(B)$ if $\Pr(A) = 0.2$, $\Pr(C) = 0.4$, and $\Pr(A \cup B \cup C) = 0.8$.

I know that $\Pr(B)$ is between .2 and .4 but how can I determine where ($B$ intersects $A$) and ($B$ intersects $C$)?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the probability of three events is

$P(A\cup B \cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B \cap C)$

Now you can replace in the  before formula, the conditions of problem say:

*$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

*$P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$

*$A\cap C=\emptyset$

God bless

Comment: So that answer makes sense to me except that means P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1.1 Anything over 1 doesn't make sense...does it?

Comment: Why not?  Independent does not mean disjoint!  For instance, think of a die roll and let $A=\{1,3,5\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then $A,B$ are independent, but $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)=7/6>1$.

Comment: The probability of $P(A_1)+P(A_2)+\cdots\leq1$ only when the sets $A_i$ form a partition of $\Omega$

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Ai form a partition of Ω"

Comment: Kike's statement is inaccurate, but what he's saying is that if you have sets $A_1,A_2,\dots$, then $\Pr(A_1)+\Pr(A_2)+\dots$ is guaranteed not to exceed one if $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are disjoint, but that if they are not disjoint then this is not necessarily true.  See my examples of independent $A,B$.

Comment: see the enlace [link](http://jeremykun.com/2013/03/28/conditional-partitioned-probability-a-primer/)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes....

$$0.8=\Pr(A\cup B \cup C) = \Pr(A\cup B) + \Pr(C) - \Pr( (A\cup B) \cap C)\\
= \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B) + \Pr(C) -\Pr( (A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C) )
=\\
\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A)\Pr(B)+\Pr(C) - \Pr(B\cap C)\\
=
\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A)\Pr(B)+\Pr(C) - \Pr(B) \Pr(C)=
0.6 +0.4\Pr(B).
$$

Hence $\Pr(B)=1/2$.

Comment: So that answer makes sense to me except that means P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1.1  Anything over 1 doesn't make sense...does it?

Comment: Why not?  Independent does not mean disjoint!  For instance, think of a die roll and let $A=\{1,3,5\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then $A,B$ are independent, but $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)=7/6>1$.